# Jenkins/Hudson JBoss management plugin

Tags: jenkins, hudson, jboss5.x

I am able to specify the IP address of my local JBoss instance through Jenkins configuration, but how do I specify the port/port binding of the deployment?

Comment: Did you try ipAddress:port ??

Comment: did not work with that. it just adds the :[port] after the IP address and it's not the correct way to start a JBoss instance